# Missing template error after adding custom validation, template exsists and works without validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

This one is a bit challenging so bear with me. Here is the summary. I added a custom validation to one of my models. After I added this everything works fine with all actions except the update action. If I restrict the new validator to only the create action, then the update action works fine. Below is the related code:

In my model

```
validate :start_must_be_before_end_time

def start_must_be_before_end_time
return if customer_start.blank? || customer_end.blank?

if customer_start > customer_end
 errors.add(:customer_start, "start time must be before end time")
end
end
```

In my controller for the update action:

```
def update
@handover = Handover.find(params[:id])
if @handover.update_attributes(params[:handover])
    UpdatedHandover.perform_async(@handover.id)
    flash[:success] = "Handover Template Updated and Approvals Sent!"
    redirect_to view_context.select_handover_cal(current_user)
  else
    flash[:error] = "Please correct the following errors in your form!"
    render edit_handover_path(@handover.id)
  end
end
```

So if the start time is before the end time in the create action, everything works fine. It renders the new action and displays the error. If this happens in the update action it gives me a missing template error for the edit action. The edit file is in the proper place and this works if the validator is restricted to the create action. I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is giving me so much trouble. This is rails 3.2.18. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try changing render edit_handover_path(@handover.id) to render 'edit'

Comment: That worked, now I just feel stupid ;) If you will answer, I'll give the question to you as deserved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better understanding of `render`:

When you use `render`, you pass the instantiated object (newly created or updated). When attempting to update the object, validation was triggered and, if somehow unsuccessful, you render `edit`, since your in memory object contains necessary validation errors.

But `edit_something_path` is used when you use `redirect_to`. When you have the object saved and you can get the persisted data from the database.

You problem can be solved in two ways:

```
render 'edit'
render :edit
# Your validation errors will persist
```

or

```
redirect_to edit_handover_path(@handover.id)
# Your validation errors will be gone
```

Comment: Thank You for the help and explination!

Comment: @acezone98 When you are clear about something, you will have the confidence. Btw, there is a nice way to appreciate answers in stackoverflow, I think you know that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass template name to render method, not a path. So if you want to render 'edit.html.erb', pass 'edit'.

Change

```
 render edit_handover_path(@handover.id)
```

to

```
 render 'edit'
```

Note that if you used extra instance variables in edit template, you would need to set them in update action.